# ANTLR mismatched input '<EOF>'

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Given the following ANTLR 4.1 grammar, with one line intentionally commented out ...

```
grammar Foobar;

//whyDoesThisRuleHelp : expression ;
expression : operand | binaryOperation ;
binaryOperation : operand WS BINARY_OPERATOR WS expression ;
operand : LETTER ;

BINARY_OPERATOR : 'EQ' ;
LETTER : [a-z] ;
WS : [ \n]+ ;
```

.. why does `echo -n "a EQ b" | grun Foobar expression` produce

```
line 1:6 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting WS
```

.. **but if we uncomment** the `block : expression ;` line above then `grun` **produces no errors**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of a rare but known bug:
[No viable alternative can be incorrectly thrown for start rules without explicit EOF](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/118)

The performance implications of properly fixing this are currently *staggering*, so we have no intention of applying the patch for the foreseeable future. The workaround is to create a rule that ends with an explicit `EOF`, and start parsing there.

Comment: I believe you, but there is no explicit EOF in my `whyDoesThisRuleHelp` rule.  Is there an interesting (or educational) reason why a rule without an explicit EOF also solves the problem? Thanks. (I read [the issue you referred to](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/118) but didn't understand any of it lol)

Comment: @JaredBeck It doesn't happen every time you are missing the `EOF`. Your two grammars (one with and one without the line commented) shows one case where it does happen, and one case where it doesn't happen.