# Antlr4.5.3 and Python 2.7 : EOF problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, antlr4, eof

I am creating a parser with Antlr 4.5.3 and Python 2.7 and am running into a problem that others have mentioned already, namely that the parser does not want to recognise an end of file.

The following post states this is a known bug and suggests the solution of explicitly including the EOF terminal symbol in the entry rule to the grammar:

[ANTLR mismatched input '<EOF>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172841/antlr-mismatched-input-eof)

So, naturally, I did this. However, I am still getting an error when I try to parse my rule file.

Here is a toy grammar I am testing on

```
grammar TestGrammar;

startRule : (basicRule)+ EOF ;
basicRule : INT ;

INT :  [0-9]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // Define whitespace rule, ignore
```

I compile using:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 TestGrammar.g4
```

My Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from antlr4 import *

from TestGrammarLexer import TestGrammarLexer
from TestGrammarParser import TestGrammarParser

from RuleParserListener import RuleParserListener

import sys

def main(argv):
    input = FileStream(argv[1])
    lexer = TestGrammarLexer(input)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = TestGrammarParser(stream)
    listener = RuleParserListener()
    parser.addParseListener(listener)

    parser.startRule()

    tree = parser.startRule()
    walker = ParseTreeWalker()
    walker.walk(listener, tree)
    print input

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

The file I am trying to parse (yes, just a single integer value with a line break) called 'test.rules':

```
19
```

The output of running the script:

```
> python RuleParser.py test.rules 
line 2:0 missing INT at '<EOF>'
19
```

This is so basic I can't understand why it is not working. I have tried with and without the ending EOF in the entrance rule, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working, or better still, have a solution?!

Thanks a lot!